# How can I install RailRoad in windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to draw class diagrams for my ruby on rails classes? I heard RailRoad is better for this. but still I cannot install it. I am working with windows. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Another alternative would be to use the free trial of Rubymine; it can generate decent model dependency diagrams

Comment: thank you.... I installed Rubymine. but where can I find model dependency diagrams in Rubymine?

Comment: I think it's in the file menu. I don't have access at the moment to verify.

Comment: thank you... I found diagrams in file/settings. I create a project in Rubymine and now I want to see my class diagrams. how can I see ? sorry for asking foolish questions...I am novel to the RoR and difficult to do even little thing in ruby

Comment: to find a model diagram right click on the project and select show model dependency diagram. then you can view model diagrams.